# ActiveMQ Java NIO transport connector vs PoolConnectionFactory

Tags: multithreading, jms, activemq-classic, connection-pooling, nio

What is the different use cases of Java NIO transport connector vs PoolConnectionFactory in ActiveMQ. Both serves the pool of connections.I want to use thousand of clients connect to the broker and maintain a seperate queue for each client. Where is is use case for both of this in the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NIO Transport connector is a server side incoming connection API that utilizes a selector based event loop to share the load of multiple active connections where normally on the normal transport connector a single thread is created per connection to process IO leading to higher thread counts when large numbers of connections are active.

The PooledConnectionFactory is a client side device that provides a pool of one or more open connections that can be used by application code to reduce the number of connection create / destroy events thereby leading to faster client side code in some cases and lower overhead on the remote broker as it would not need to process connection create / destroy events from an application whose model causes this sort of behavior.  Depending on how you've coded your application or what API layering you have such as Camel or Spring etc a pool may or may not be of benefit.

The two things are not related and should not be equated with one another.